# Python threading in IOS

Tags: python, multithreading, kivy, ios-simulator, python-multithreading

I made a chat streaming function in python using threading which is for a kivy app when I compile the app for iOS the thread updates when the app starts and doesn’t update again when the streaming is updated. It works perfecting when I run it in pycharm but it not updating in IOS simulator. I was wondering maybe it’s because I’m using an IOS simulator to run the code but I’m not sure. Any body with expertise on this area I would appreciate if you assist me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Deployed it on my phone and it works as expected.